# jquery click event not binding

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've got a wordpress site running.   I've bound a jquery click event to a `<div>` tag using the ID as a selector.

The relevant code is below:
js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#homepage_contact_form" ).click(function() {
          alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
        });
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="homepage_contact_form" class="et_pb_module et_pb_contact_form_container clearfix  et_pb_contact_form_0">
```

However, **the event is not triggering.**

The thing works if I simulate it in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/yL4gjc1d/), but it doesn't work on the actual page.

Relevant information:

- This is a Wordpress site using the Divi theme.  The js is being inserted through the ePanel
- You can find the actual page with the source code above at http://www.inkcorporate.com

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console on your WordPress site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your jquery library file there is `jQuery.noConflict();`

This means the the `$` is not available and you will have to use `jQuery` instead

```js
// use jQuery as the initial object and pass $ in as 
// the parameter to the ready method so that $ is available inside it
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#homepage_contact_form").click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked.   Excellent and thanks.   Very similar to the answer below, but the $ inside the function had to be there for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace all $ by jQuery. I think it works with:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( "#homepage_contact_form" ).click(function() {
          alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
        });
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nope, that did not help.  The answer I marked as correct actually did the job.   Since yours was similar, I've up-voted it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the jQuery library on your page?
eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you put it before the link to your local .js file as well.